# Android and calculating the size of a one-line string in a given font and font size?

Tags: android, string, fonts, size

Is there an API method for calculating the size (i.e. width and height) of a string displayed on one line and in a given font and font size?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setTypeface(TypeFace obj); // if custom font use `TypeFace.createFromFile`
p.setTextSize(float size);
float textWidth = p.measureText("Your string"); 
// you get the width here and textsize is the height.
```

Answer (score 8):

```
Paint mPaint = new Paint();
mPaint.setTextSize(/*put here ur size*/);
mPaint.setTypeface(/* put here ur font type */);
Rect bounds = new Rect();
mPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
```

then make the call of

```
bounds.width();

bounds.height();
```

Answer (score 2):

The Paint class has a method measureText() which will give you the width in float

```
Paint p = new Paint();
int INFO_WINDOW_WIDTH = (int)p.measureText("this is string");
```

and another is [Paint.getTextBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#getTextBounds%28char%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Rect%29)